# microstrip patch antenna representation as an array of two slots

Tags: antenna, microstrip

from the article bellow we can see the microstrip antenna as an array of two radiating slots which are separated by half a wavelength
As shown in the photo bellow.these Electric fields cause magnetic current in the same direction at every slot.

Why becase of the same magnetic direction we get a stronger radiation pattern?
i cant see it in the equation bellow.
Why we get constructive sum of both radiations?
Thanks.
https://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/faculty/nikolova/antenna_dload/current_lectures/L21_Mstrip2.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]